# Number of divisors of $2^k+1$

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n$ be distinct primes greater than $3$ and $k=p_1p_2 \ldots p_n$. It is a known result that $2^{k}+1$ has at least $4^n$ divisors (this was a shortlisted problem from IMO 2002 - N3).

Is it true that $2^{k}+1$ has at least $(n+1) \cdot 2^{2^n-n}$ divisors? Can this bound be improved?

Comment: Yes, it actually be improved to $2^{2^n}$ using Zsigmondy's theorm